# Iterate and checking an array with for of loop and if..else statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am trying to make an array with names, then to iterate them using a for of loop and then to check the iteration using a if else statement. My code is below, but it did not work, I saw no result. I tried with for in, the same bad result. In Html file I have a paraghraph with demo id and a button with function for iterate and checking array

```
function availableName() {

 const check = document.getElementById('userID');
 const takenNames=['manuel','remus','manuel-remus','tomi','mirel'];
 const reservedNames=['cristina','angela','rusanda','costantin'];
 const givenNames=[...takenNames, ...reservedNames];

  for (givenName of givenNames) {
  if (givenName === check) {
      sayMessage=givenName +"Not available!";
 }
 else {
   sayMessage= givenName +"Available";
 }

 }
document.getElementById("available").innerHTML= sayMessage;
 };
```

Comment: it `document.getElementById('userID')` should be `document.getElementById('userID').value` if userId is an input

Comment: Try `if ( givenName === check.value )`, as check is actually a dom element not the value of element itself.

Comment: the question is not clear.. give js fiddle demo, 
what exactly is givenNames? what is desired output of sayMessage for above example. I have created sample js fiddle demo here:- https://jsfiddle.net/rbb1af2o/8/  Check and modify this

Comment: @maverick `givenNames` is a combination of both `takenNames` and `resrevedNames`.

Comment: Check my fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/rbb1af2o/8/ I am able to print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to get the value of the `input`using `.value` as stated in comments.

Then to check its existence in the `array` you can use one of **[`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)**'s built-in methods, such as **[`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** or **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**.

This is how should be your code:

```
function availableName() {
  const check = document.getElementById('userID').value;
  const takenNames = ['manuel', 'remus', 'manuel-remus', 'tomi', 'mirel'];
  const reservedNames = ['cristina', 'angela', 'rusanda', 'costantin'];
  const givenNames = [...takenNames, ...reservedNames];

  if (givenNames.indexOf(check) > 0) {
    sayMessage = check + " Not available!";
  } else {
    sayMessage = check + " Available";
  }
  document.getElementById("available").innerHTML = sayMessage;
};
```

**Demo:**

This is a Demo:

```js
function availableName() {
  //const check = document.getElementById('userID').value;
  const check = "cristina";
  const takenNames = ['manuel', 'remus', 'manuel-remus', 'tomi', 'mirel'];
  const reservedNames = ['cristina', 'angela', 'rusanda', 'costantin'];
  const givenNames = [...takenNames, ...reservedNames];

  if (givenNames.indexOf(check) > 0) {
    sayMessage = check + " Not available!";
  } else {
    sayMessage = check + " Available";
  }
  document.getElementById("available").innerHTML = sayMessage;
};

availableName();
```

```html
<div id="available"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the function isInArray?

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

function availableName() {
const check = document.getElementById('userID');
 const takenNames=['manuel','remus','manuel-remus','tomi','mirel'];
 const reservedNames=['cristina','angela','rusanda','costantin'];
 const givenNames=[...takenNames, ...reservedNames];
for (givenName of givenNames) {
  if (isInArray(check, givenNames)) {
      sayMessage=givenName +"Not available!";
 }
 else {
   sayMessage= givenName +"Available";
 }

 }
document.getElementById("available").innerHTML= sayMessage;
 };
```